# How to get total sum result from 2 array and split into multiple input?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Well im still new into javascript and need some help about getting total sum of 2 select which each option having different array. Plus, the total sum will be shown at multiple input. (I dont know what is this method called).

I tried and google alot still does not works and I know some code is missing.
That Output1 and Output2 just to check that they are calling the array.

```
<select id="firstselect" onchange="total()">
<option value="0"> Choose </option>
<option value="1"> Option A </option>
<option value="2"> Option B </option>
</select>

<select id="secondselect" onchange="total()">
<option value="0"> Choose </option>
<option value="1"> Option D </option>
<option value="2"> Option E </option>
</select>

<p id="output1"></p> 
<p id="output2"></p>


<input id="inputA" disabled> INPUT A </input> 
<input id="inputB" disabled> INPUT B </input> 
<input id="inputC" disabled> INPUT C </input>
<input id="inputD" disabled> INPUT D </input> 
<input id="inputE" disabled> INPUT E </input> 
<input id="inputF" disabled> INPUT F </input>


var inputA = document.getElementById("inputA");
var inputB = document.getElementById("inputB");
var inputC = document.getElementById("inputC");
var inputD = document.getElementById("inputD");
var inputE = document.getElementById("inputE");
var inputF = document.getElementById("inputF");

//FIRSTSELECT   0=inputA, 1=inputB 2=inputC 3=inputD 4=inputE 5=inputF  
var value1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
var value2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]; 

//SECONDSELECT  0=inputA, 1=inputB 2=inputC 3=inputD 4=inputE 5=inputF  
var value3 = [2,3,4,5,6,7];
var value4 = [3,4,5,6,7,8]; 

function fs1() {
var fs = document.getElementById('firstselect').value;
if(fs == 0) {fs = 0;}
if(fs == 1) {fs = value1;}
if(fs == 2) {fs = value2;}
document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = fs ;
return fs;
inputA.value = fs[0];
inputB.value = fs[1];
inputC.value = fs[2];
inputD.value = fs[3];
inputE.value = fs[4];
inputF.value = fs[5];
}
function ss1(){
var ss = document.getElementById('secondselect').value;
if(ss == 0) {ss = 0;}
if(ss == 1) {ss = value3;}
if(ss == 2) {ss = value4;}  
document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = ss;
return ss;
inputA.value = ss[0];
inputB.value = ss[1];
inputC.value = ss[2];
inputD.value = ss[3];
inputE.value = ss[4];
inputF.value = ss[5];
}
function total(){
var total = parseInt(fs1()) + parseInt(ss1());
}
```

The result should be like this :
inputA.value = fs[0] + ss[0], 
inputB.value = fs[1] + ss[1] and it goes until [5]

Comment: You might consider using consistent indentation when writing code - it'll make reading and debugging it much easier, not only for potential answerers, but for you as well, when we can all see the `{` `}` blocks and their nesting level at a glance, rather than having to carefully pick through each line just to pick up on the logical paths.

Comment: You need .reduce() array helper method, to calculate the sum of array. I would love to help, but I don't really understand what you try to say, maybe mock up would be better than the example code, or a js fiddle.

Comment: ya, i explain so badly ahaha, I will do better next time..thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, I hope it fits
It works!

```js
//FIRSTSELECT   0=inputA, 1=inputB 2=inputC 3=inputD 4=inputE 5=inputF  
        var value1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
        var value2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]; 

        //SECONDSELECT  0=inputA, 1=inputB 2=inputC 3=inputD 4=inputE 5=inputF  
        var value3 = [2,3,4,5,6,7];
        var value4 = [3,4,5,6,7,8]; 

        function ss(){
            var ss = document.getElementById('secondselect').value;
            if(ss == 0) {ss = 0;}
            if(ss == 1) {ss = value3;}
            if(ss == 2) {ss = value4;}  
            document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = ss;
            return ss;
        }

        function fs1() {
            var fs = document.getElementById('firstselect').value;
            if(fs == 0) {fs = 0;}
            if(fs == 1) {fs = value1;}
            if(fs == 2) {fs = value2;}
            document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = fs ;
            return fs;
           
        }
        
       
        
        function total(){
            
           
            debugger;
            var  fs=fs1();
            var  ss1=ss();
            var arrResult=[];
            if(fs && fs.length>0 && ss1 && ss1.length>0 ){
                for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {    
                    arrResult.push(+fs[i] + +ss1[i])  
                }
            }
            
            
            var inputA = document.getElementById("inputA");
            var inputB = document.getElementById("inputB");
            var inputC = document.getElementById("inputC");
            var inputD = document.getElementById("inputD");
            var inputE = document.getElementById("inputE");
            var inputF = document.getElementById("inputF");
        
            inputA.value = arrResult[0]?arrResult[0]:'';
            inputB.value = arrResult[1]?arrResult[1]:'';
            inputC.value = arrResult[2]?arrResult[2]:'';
            inputD.value = arrResult[3]?arrResult[3]:'';
            inputE.value = arrResult[4]?arrResult[4]:'';
            inputF.value = arrResult[5]?arrResult[5]:'';

        }
```

```html
<select id="firstselect" onchange="total()">
            <option value="0"> Choose </option>
            <option value="1"> Option A </option>
            <option value="2"> Option B </option>
        </select>
        
        <select id="secondselect" onchange="total()">
            <option value="0"> Choose </option>
            <option value="1"> Option D </option>
            <option value="2"> Option E </option>
        </select>
        
        <p id="output1"></p> 
        <p id="output2"></p>
        
        
        <input id="inputA" disabled> INPUT A </input> 
        <input id="inputB" disabled> INPUT B </input> 
        <input id="inputC" disabled> INPUT C </input>
        <input id="inputD" disabled> INPUT D </input> 
        <input id="inputE" disabled> INPUT E </input> 
        <input id="inputF" disabled> INPUT F </input>
```

Comment: well thanks @adina , sorry for bad explanation and yeah, that what i meant the result should be... 
You see that when I choose the first select option, why the input section not showing any data from array that i chose? unless it shown when the second select option was choosen (the sum of that two select option begins and showing results).

Comment: nvm then, just found out the solution by creating new variable with 0 value with the same .length then use the new variable on this statement : if(fs == 0) {fs = newvariable;}. Thanks again StackOverFlow community awesome! .